# validación al realizar el guardado de datos en modelo ASP. NET CORE MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Vengo con una pequeña duda al momento de realizar el guardado de mis datos, previa validacion del modelo, existirá la posibilidad de hacer una validación de que si mi input contiene informacion o algun dato, hacer la conversión a mayúscula, en el código justo coloco una linea en comentarios en donde quisiera saber si se puede realizar o no algún tipo de validación.

```
 private async Task<bool> Guardar_Paciente_Async()
    {
        _dataInput = MODEL_PACIENTE;
        var valor = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var PacLista = _context.TBL_PACIENTE.Where(u => u.PAC_RUT.Equals(MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_RUT)).ToList();
            if (PacLista.Count.Equals(0))
            {
                var strategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
                await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
                {
                    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var imagenByte = await _lCargarImagen.ByteAvatarImageAsync(MODEL_PACIENTE.AvatarImage, _environment, "images/user_icon.png");
                            string TmpCodPac = _dataInput.PAC_COD_ODONT;
                            String vfCodPac = TmpCodPac.Substring(0, 4);
                            var Nuevo_Paciente = new MODELO_PACIENTE
                            {
                                PAC_CODIGO = _dataInput.PAC_CODIGO,
                                PAC_NOMBRE = _dataInput.PAC_NOMBRE.ToUpper(),
                                PAC_APELLIDO = _dataInput.PAC_APELLIDO.ToUpper(),
                                PAC_SEXO = _dataInput.PAC_SEXO,
                                PAC_RUT = _dataInput.PAC_RUT,
                                PAC_FECHA_NAC = _dataInput.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                                PAC_EDAD = _dataInput.PAC_EDAD,
                                PAC_REPRESENTANTE = _dataInput.PAC_REPRESENTANTE.ToUpper(),
    //SE PUEDE PONER AQUI UN IF PARA VALIDAR SI ES UN CAMPO VACIO NO LO CONVIERTA A MAYUSCULA?
                                PAC_DIRECCION = _dataInput.PAC_DIRECCION.ToUpper(),
                                PAC_COMUNA = _dataInput.PAC_COMUNA,
                                PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS = _dataInput.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                                PAC_TELEFONO = _dataInput.PAC_TELEFONO,
                                PAC_CORREO = _dataInput.PAC_CORREO,
                                PAC_CONVENIO = _dataInput.PAC_CONVENIO,
                                PAC_PREVISIONES = _dataInput.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                                PAC_OBSERVACIONES = _dataInput.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                                PAC_COD_ODONT = vfCodPac,
                                PAC_IMAGEN = imagenByte,
                                PAC_FEC_REG = DateTime.Now,
                                PAC_FEC_ACT = DateTime.Now

                            };
                            await _context.AddAsync(Nuevo_Paciente);
                            _context.SaveChanges();
                            transaction.Commit();
                            _dataInput = null;
                            valor = true;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            _dataInput.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            valor = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                _dataInput.ErrorMessage = $"El RUT {MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_RUT} ya se encuentra Registrado";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
            {
                foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
                {
                    _dataInput.ErrorMessage += error.ErrorMessage;
                }
            }
            valor = false;
        }
        return valor;

    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda o guía para poder solventar este problema.

Comment: Hola, me imagino que quiera hacer esa validación xq si viene *null* y esto rompe `PAC_REPRESENTANTE = _dataInput.PAC_REPRESENTANTE.ToUpper(),` para evitar eso solo tiene q hacer `PAC_REPRESENTANTE = _dataInput.PAC_REPRESENTANTE?.ToUpper(),` con esa variante el método `ToUpper()` solo se llama si `PAC_REPRESENTANTE` es distinto de *null*

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente era lo que necesitaba.